# chmod +x seems not to add the command

Tags: command-line, permissions, chmod

I'm trying to set up the High Precision AD/DA Board from Waveform. The last step is to run `sudo ./dac8532_test`, where it notes in the instructions that if command not found, to run `chmod +x`. The command was not found, so I ran `chmod +x dac8532_test` and tried `sudo ./dac8532_test` again.

The command was again not found (`sudo: ./dac8532_test: command not found`). I checked and the file dac8532_test is indeed in the directory I'm in (there are two other files with that name, but they have the extensions .c and .o if that matters).

What am I doing wrong? (Note: if there's any information I need to add, please let me know; I wasn't sure what was necessary.)

Output of `file dac8532_test`:

```
dac8532_test: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=ff54034576038bbed2b96bce738f008281aa7d28, not stripped
```

Output of `ls -al dac8532_test`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 59232 Jun 29 11:07 dac8532_test
```

Comment: Is dac8532_test a binary or script? If it is a script, check that the commands the script uses actually exist.

Comment: @BernardWei I'm pretty sure it's a binary. (I used nano to look at it and it is just a bunch of special characters, nothing readable at all.)

Comment: when you do a "ls -la dac8532_test", do you see execution flag set for the file? If not, try doing the chmod with sudo,  like "sudo chmod a+rx dac8532_test" and try running it again.

Comment: @Terrance I tried doing that just now and again got "command not found".

Comment: @BernardWei I don't see the execution flag (which is `x`, right?) set; I ran sudo chmod a+rx and again got command not found.

Comment: Please add output of  `file dac8532_test` and `ls -al dac8532_test` to the question.

Comment: @Terrance it's in the question: `sudo: ./dac8532_test: command not found` when I type in `sudo ./dac8532_test`.

Comment: Hmm...  if you do a ls -la again, and if you don't see something like -rwxr-xr-x r, your drive may be mounted as non-executable.... check if your drive is mounted with noexec. If so, you either need to enable it or move the file to another drive before you can execute it. Use "df ." to find out which mount is your current directory located, and use "mount" to list all the mounts, check for any noexec flag.

Comment: @N0rbert added.

Comment: @Terrance running `chmod` gives me no errors. Trying `sudo sh` again gives me command not found.

Comment: Please note: `dac8532_test` is built for ARM CPU, so it will not launch on default x86_64 Ubuntu desktop. Where do you running it - on board or on desktop?

Comment: @N0rbert I'm running it on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: What type of storage / filesystem is the file on? if it is on external media, it's possible that the filesystem doesn't support the *nix style execute bit

Comment: @steeldriver it's on a usb drive - i can move it off, though. i'll do that real quick and see if it fixes it.

Comment: @steeldriver there we go, it's working now. Thank you! If you write that up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @heather glad we got to the bottom of the issue - I've marked it as a duplicate since it's come up a few times already